# Android: does DownloadManager download files as a FIFO or simultaneously

Tags: android, xamarin, restsharp, android-download-manager

I have a requirement for my applicaiton which have to download the files in silent mode and some files are in non-silent mode. Silent mode is when application is starting to download the file, the user have no idea the application is downloading. Whereas Non-silent mode, the user will know the file is downloading.

In this case, Non-silent and silent mode can be downloaded simultaneously but each of them can only download one at a time.

I thought of using DownloadManager but not sure whether the DownloadManager will have these type of ability for to control it.

I currently have a RestSharp library to communicate with server. When I researched on google, RestSharp library doesn't seems to have a way of monitor to downloading progress.

Is there other library for xamarin which support monitoring the downloading progress.

Comment: you mean `DownloadManager#query`?

Comment: I am new to DownloadManager, I don't know does it download  simultaneously or download one by one.

Comment: the docs dont say how it is done, so i think it can be different on different devices

Comment: @SushiHangover good to know, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android OS creates a dedicated thread pool for this purpose and the number of threads created is based on an internally defined resource-based integer so it can be adjusted per API release, device requirements, etc...

Also if you look at the download queue management, it is FIFO-based, so the first **X number** of Uris that are **not** failed, paused, disallowed for the current network (wifi, cellular) type, etc..  will be available to downloading.

#### Defined in the [Download](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/src/com/android/providers/downloads/DownloadService.java) manager as;

```
final int maxConcurrent = Resources.getSystem().getInteger( com.android.internal.R.integer.config_MaxConcurrentDownloadsAllowed);
```

Thus it is not a fixed number, but to find out how many threads are available for downloading grab the internal integer resource `config_MaxConcurrentDownloadsAllowed`:

#### Java:

---

```
int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("config_MaxConcurrentDownloadsAllowed", "integer", "android");
int maxConcurrentDownloadsAllowed = Resources.getSystem().getInteger(id);
```

---

#### C#

---

```
var id = Resources.GetIdentifier("config_MaxConcurrentDownloadsAllowed", "integer", "android");
var maxConcurrentDownloadsAllowed = Resources.GetInteger(id);
```

#### Note:

Personally on most devices that I have run unit-tests against, it is **5**, but I seen this as low **1** on the lowest-end Android phone that I ever saw and that cost $5 ;-) and on a custom-built CDN-style Android server it was **50**

Comment: Will it redownload after reboot from shutdown

Comment: @Simon "The download manager will conduct the download in the background, taking care of HTTP interactions and retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and **system reboots**." @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html